# Does there exists a nontrivial group homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}/2^n\Bbb{Z}$ ($n\in \Bbb{Z}$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, modules, group-homomorphism

> Does there exists a nontrivial group homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}/2^n\Bbb{Z}$ ($n\ge 1$)?

Suppose there exists a group homomorphism $f:\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}/2^n\Bbb{Z}$. For some $a\in \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$, $f(a)=b$, $b\in\Bbb{Z}/2^n\Bbb{Z}$.

Then, $f(2^na)=0$.
I cannot proceed from here.
I want to solve this question by myself, so only just a hint is also appreciated.

Comment: You must assume $n \ge 0$ or the problem does not make sense. Suppose the homomorphism if surjective and $f(a)=b$ is a generator of $Z/2^nZ$. What could the image of $a/2$ be?

Comment: @Derek Holt.  If such $a$ exists, $b$ should be $2$-divisible. But $b$ is not $2$-divisible. By the same reason, there is no nontrivial homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ to torsion group. Am I go on the right track ?

Comment: Sounds good! In fact there is no nontrivial homomorphism from ${\mathbb Q}$ to any torsion group, which is a stronger statement.